# three Cron jobs runs every two days alternatively not in same day

Tags: cron

How can i set three cron jobs for every two days interval but not runs all.

This is is my three cron job process:

```
    0 20 */2 * * /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/html/data_download1.rb >/dev/null 2>&1
    0 20 */2 * * /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/html/data_download2.rb >/dev/null 2>&1
    0 20 */2 * * /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/html/data_download3.rb >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `1-31/2` for one task and `2-30/2` for the other to specify alternating days. This will fail on months with odd numbers of days as the `1-31/2` job will run twice in a row.

If you absolutely must have it right, you can check whether the number of days since a particular date is odd or even and have one script abort if it's odd and the other abort if it's even.

Comment: Can you Explain with script using my example?

Comment: Not quite, because I can't understand exactly what effect you want. You have three scripts that are supposed to run every other day. Does that mean an alternate days you want two scripts to run?

Comment: Then replace the `*/2` with `1-31/2` on two of the lines and `2-30/2` on the other.